# Linear algebra problem about eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Please help with the following linear algebra problem.

Suppose the following information is known about a matrix A:
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
4
\end{bmatrix}
=
9\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-3\\ 
9
\end{bmatrix}
=
2\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-3\\ 
9
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
3\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

a) Please find eigenvalues.
b) Please find eigenvectors.
c) Is A invertible? Please explain...
d) Is A diagonalizable? Please explain...

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Answer (score 1):

You can read off two eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the second and third equations. The first equation is presenting you an $x$ which is independent of the two eigenvectors and which is mapped into one of the eigenspaces. This means that there is an eigenvector whose eigenvalue is zero (since we've mapped three independent vectors into the span of only two independent vectors). You can identify this eigenvector by appropriately combining equations 1 and 3. This should get you to your answers for c and d.

Comment: I see the case for equations 2 and 3, I can get eigenvalues and eigenvectors directly for them. I ask you to please explain how equations 1 and 3 can be combined.

Comment: Multiply equation $1$ by $-1/3$ and then add equations $1$ and $3$. Then the right side will be zero and the left side will be $Ax$ for some $x$.

Comment: Yes. On the right side this is trivial. On the left side it follows from linearity of $A$: $(-1/3) Ax = A ((-1/3) x)$.

Comment: So, the result will be --- A[(-1/3) (-2/3) (-4/3) = -3[1  1  1] and then I add left sides and right sides of both equstions to get A[(2/3) (1/3) (-1/3)] = 0[1  1  1] which can be represented as A[(2/3) (1/3) (-1/3)] = 0[(2/3) (1/3) (-1/3)] and so this eigenvalue equals zero. Am I correct?

Comment: Perfect. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Then I can say that A is not invertible because there shouldn´t be eigenvalues equal to zero. Is this correct? What about diagonalizable? I have read that a matrix is diagonalizable if eigenvalues are different. Is matrix A diagonalizable?

Comment: Here your eigenvalues are $0,2,3$, from what we've been saying. What does this tell you?

Comment: It seems to me that matrix A is not invertible because one eigenvalue equals zero. I do not know what to say about diagonalizable.

Comment: As you've said, an $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable. Your matrix is $3 \times 3$ and has three distinct eigenvalues, so it is diagonalizable.